# Could not read script ‘/’ as it is a directory. Expo Android Build via Expo Managed workflow

Tags: react-native, gradle, expo

I’m building my application and facing issues with the Android Play Store build while the internal Android build works fine with the following command.

Also I’m building via expo managed workflow

```
eas build --platform android --profile production
```

I’m getting the following error log.

> Running ‘gradlew :app:bundleRelease’ in
> /home/expo/workingdir/build/androidDownloading
> https://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-7.5.1-all.zip Welcome
> to Gradle 7.5.1!Here are the highlights of this release: - Support for
> Java 18 - Support for building with Groovy 4 - Much more responsive
> continuous builds- Improved diagnostics for dependency resolutionFor
> more details see honour the JVM settings for this build a single-use
> Daemon process will be forked. See The Gradle Daemon will be stopped
> at the end of the buildFAILURE:Build failed with an exception.*
> Where:Settings file
> ‘/home/expo/workingdir/build/android/settings.gradle’ line: 6
>
> - What went wrong:A problem occurred evaluating settings ‘ProjectName’.> Could not read script ‘/’ as it is a directory.* Try:>
>   Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace.> Run with --info
>   or --debug option to get more log output.> Run with --scan to get full
>   insights.* Get more help at BUILD FAILED in 14sError: Gradle build
>   failed with unknown error. See logs for the “Run gradlew” phase for
>   more information.

I have the following configurations on my local machine.

```
System:
OS: macOS 13.4.1
CPU: (8) arm64 Apple M1
Memory: 564.08 MB / 16.00 GB
Shell: 5.9 - /bin/zsh
Binaries:
Node: 18.18.2 - ~/.nvm/versions/node/v18.18.2/bin/node
Yarn: 1.22.19 - /opt/homebrew/bin/yarn
npm: 8.19.4 - ~/Desktop/folio3projects/projectname-mobile/node_modules/.bin/npm
Watchman: 2023.10.09.00 - /opt/homebrew/bin/watchman
Managers:
CocoaPods: 1.13.0 - /usr/local/bin/pod
SDKs:
iOS SDK:
Platforms: DriverKit 22.2, iOS 16.2, macOS 13.1, tvOS 16.1, watchOS 9.1
Android SDK: Not Found
IDEs:
Android Studio: 2022.3 AI-223.8836.35.2231.10811636
Xcode: 14.2/14C18 - /usr/bin/xcodebuild
Languages:
Java: 11.0.21 - /usr/bin/javac
npmPackages:
@react-native-community/cli: Not Found
react: 18.2.0 => 18.2.0
react-native: 0.71.14 => 0.71.14
react-native-macos: Not Found
npmGlobalPackages:
react-native: Not Found
```

I’ve tried upgrading and downgrading expo SDK and eas CLI as well. Still no luck

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After running `expo doctor` we found out some dev dependencies issues & have some conflicting dependencies. Removed unused libraries & updated expo to latest SDK 49